# Dual-booting with GRUB bootloader causes Windows 10 to hibernate instead of sleep

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub, sleep, kali-linux

When I dual-boot with Windows 10 and Kali using GRUB bootloader, I cannot get my laptop to go to sleep. When I close the lid, everything seems fine. But when I come back to open the lid, it opens to GRUB as if it has been shut down. However, once in Windows everything works as if it had gone to sleep. This is very annoying because every time I close the lid of my laptop, it adds an extra 10-15 seconds to when I can start using it.

Comment: You should edit your question adding your files `/etc/default/grub` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, so people can reconstruct what grub is actually doing at boot time and propose options to be set.

Comment: The German page https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bootoptionen/#Weitere-Bootoptionen gives a good comprehension about boot options. Look for options related to 'ACPI' to get an idea. I did not find an English version of that page.

Comment: I don't really know much about GRUB, or this website really. How should I post these files? Am I able to upload them directly, or do something else?
Sorry for the nooby questions, but I barely got this duel-boot working and I'm trying to get this to work out. Thanks!

Comment: Click the [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1231013/edit) link below your question post. Copy'n'paste your content and select it. Above the editor there is a button `{}` for formatted code. It does nothing more than indentation of the selected content in the editor field with 4 spaces. You can pre-indent code in your local editor or manually add spaces as well (4 spaces at top level).

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. I'm away from my laptop for the next 2 weeks. When I get back I'll try to follow those instructions and post all the information you might need. Thanks!